# Counting Rows From a Value in a SQL text box - please please can anyone help?

Tags: sql-server-2012, aggregate, count, sum, regular-expression

I just can't find an example of this anywhere and hoping someone can help.

I have a query which returns a list of care services and other fields based on the care service table values and calculated expressions. One of the calculated expressions for each row is as follows:

```
=iif(Fields!NoCareInspection.Value=0,1,0)+
iif(Fields!NoCareInspection.Value>2,1,0)+
iif((Fields!IncidentsPrevMth.Value-(Fields!NoofIncidentsLast12.Value/12)>0 AND 
 Fields!IncidentsPrev2ndMth.Value-(Fields!NoofIncidentsLast12.Value/12)>0),1,0)+
iif(Fields!ConcernsPer100Last12.Value-Avg(Fields!ConcernsPer100Last12.Value, "DataSet2")>0,1,0)+
iif(Fields!CurrManagerStatus.Value <> "Registered",1,0)+
iif((Fields!ManagerApplicationsLast24.Value+Fields!AbsencesLast24.Value)>2,1,0)+
iif((Fields!ENFMeetingsLast24.Value+Fields!FTCsLast24.Value+Fields!INsLast24.Value+Fields!NOPsLast24.Value+Fields!UPsLast24.Value)>0,1,0)+
iif(Fields!IncidentsPrev3Mths.Value =0,1,0)+
iif(Fields!NoofAFIsLast12.Value-Avg(Fields!NoofAFIsLast12.Value, "DataSet2")>0,1,0)+
iif(Fields!RPNotReg.Value >0,1,0)
```

This evaluates a number of field values from the care homes table and nicely calculates a risk score for each care home (row) -this works a charm.

Now what I need is a summary table to count how many rows had a total score of 0,1,2 and so forth. What I have tried is different permutations of this kind of statement:

```
=SUM(iif(iif(Fields!NoCareInspection.Value=0,1,0)+
iif(Fields!NoCareInspection.Value>2,1,0)+
iif((Fields!IncidentsPrevMth.Value-(Fields!NoofIncidentsLast12.Value/12)>0 AND
Fields!IncidentsPrev2ndMth.Value-(Fields!NoofIncidentsLast12.Value/12)>0),1,0)+
iif(Fields!ConcernsPer100Last12.Value-Avg(Fields!ConcernsPer100Last12.Value, "DataSet2")>0,1,0)+
iif(Fields!CurrManagerStatus.Value <> "Registered",1,0)+
iif((Fields!ManagerApplicationsLast24.Value+Fields!AbsencesLast24.Value)>2,1,0)+
iif((Fields!ENFMeetingsLast24.Value+Fields!FTCsLast24.Value+Fields!INsLast24.Value+Fields!NOPsLast24.Value+Fields!UPsLast24.Value)>0,1,0)+
iif(Fields!IncidentsPrev3Mths.Value =0,1,0)+
iif(Fields!NoofAFIsLast12.Value-Avg(Fields!NoofAFIsLast12.Value, "DataSet2")>0,1,0)+
iif(Fields!RPNotReg.Value >0,1,0)=1,1,0))
```

I thought it was going to run but got this message:
'Inner aggregates cannot specify a dataset scope'

I have spent a few days trying to untangle this - any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't do these calculations in your data source at the database level? Maintainability of complex expressions in the SSRS expression window is pretty poor, the longer the expression is.

Comment: I usually do it at query level rather than expressions - problem is that some of the criteria is based on dataset totals/averages, eg, Avg(Fields!ConcernsPer100Last12.Value, "DataSet2"), which I cant incorporate at query level as I need everything grouped at service level

Comment: As I said, really struggling with this. Any guidance will be greatly rejoiced in!

Comment: At the query level you can use [window aggregation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql) to get aggregate values across the dataset without grouping across the dataset.  Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218902/the-sql-over-clause-when-and-why-is-it-useful/6219648#6219648.  That query has no GROUP BY of its own, so it's mixing `DetailValue` and `AGG(DetailValue) OVER ()`.  If yours is a GROUP BY query, then it would be `AGG(DetailValue)` and `AGG(AGG(DetailValue)) OVER ()`.

Comment: Thanks a million for this!

Comment: Hi, I am still going around all the houses with this - it should be so straightforward. I found 'half' a solution by means of a report footer in which i can add an expression like this:         SUM(IIF(ReportItems!Textbox5.Value = 1,1,0)). The expression above is within Textbox5 so I was hoping this could be a workaround. I dont get an error message but it is only returning a count of 4 instead of 143. Has anyone else used this type of thing before - any pointers would be hugely appreciated